# GWT-JSNI pass list of objects as params

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, jsni

Consider I have a function,

```
 public static native void mymethod(CustomObj1 a, List<CustomObj2> list) /*-{
    $wnd.MyApp.GWT.handleFile = $entry(@com.xxx.yyy.client::handleFile(Lcom/xxx/yyy/CustomObj1;));
    $wnd.MyApp.FileReader.readF(a);
}-*/;
```

and,

```
private static void handleFile(CustomObj1 a) {

}
```

,

Inside the readF function mentioned, I have,

```
 MyApp.GWT.handleFile(mmm);
```

So i need to pass the param of list of objects from mymethod to the function handleFile. By making the function as

```
private static void handleFile(CustomObj1 a, List<CustomObj2> b) {}
```

So how to set the $wnd.MyApp.GWT.handleFile such that i can pass, and the readF function also have to take the object. Assume the list wont be touched inside the readF function, rather its just a way to pass the params.

Comment: please, try to re-write your question. It is a bit confusing. Maybe write all the code in the same block, and be a bit more careful with names. Also, where `zipContents` come from?

Comment: Do you have the opportunity use the [JsInterop](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html)?